# React native web split point

Tags: reactjs, react-native-web

I am using [react native web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) to develop my web application.

I want to create code-split for my web application.

From my research on the web, I found that react web application has some code-split methods, which is shown in https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Does react native web supports these code-split techniques: import(), react.lazy, and other techniques shown in the code-splitting.html?

Answer (score -1):

Don't know whether it is currently supported.

Comment: If you are not sure about anything just comment, don't add it as an answer.